# Default Node.js + Express.js does not run

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express

I am trying to learn to create web apps with `nodejs` and `expressjs`, following the getting started guide found at [the expressjs website](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), under the heading **Using express(1) to generate an app**.

I generated an app using the `express-generator` plugin, ran `npm install`, and then attempted to run the application by using `node app` (I also tried `node app.js` for good measure. When running either of these commands, there is no output to the terminal whatsoever.

I also tried to debug the application using `node debug app`, with the following results:

```
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in app.js:1
  1 var express = require('express');
  2 var http = require('http');
  3 var path = require('path');
debug> cont
program terminated
debug> cont
App isn't running... Try `run` instead
debug>
```

I did find a file `bin/www` that seemed to contain the code to start the server, and, sure enough, running `node bin/www` succeeded in starting the application.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looks like the way to start app has changed. Instead of `node app` you should now do

`npm start`

More details here https://github.com/expressjs/generator

Comment: Wow over a year later and the getting started docs are still out of date!

Answer (score 0):

Certain `node.js` apps may try to daemonize or fork themselves when you start them.

For example, [`haraka`](https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka/blob/master/server.js#L53) uses the npm [`daemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daemon) module.  In order to avoid the original process exiting, you will usually have to either disable daemon mode in the app, or try to use the debugger `repl` to bypass the part of the code that daemonizes.

For example, with `haraka` set a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka/blob/master/server.js#L54):

```
server.js:

  53 Server.daemonize = function () {
->54     var c = this.cfg.main;
  55     if (!c.daemonize) return;
```

then:

1. Type `repl` in the `debug>` console
2. Type `this.cfg.main.daemonize = false`
3. Press `Ctrl+c` once to exit `repl`
4. Continue debugging...

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bit late to answer the question still adding `app.listen()` enables the app to be started directly by `node app.js`

`app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Starting on port:",port)
  }
)`