# cound't start express app using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I do nodemon it's fine but too bad nodemon isn't restart the app when something happened.

Where's what i've tried in my ubuntu server :

1. `npm install pm2 -g`
2. go to my app directory and do `pm2 start app.js`
3. `pm2 startup ubuntu`

My app still has 502 bad gateway error. Sigh why does this happens? I do `nodemon` it's running.. Strange thing is in the terminal pm2 did show an app and it's online :(

Comment: Have you tried curl? Have checked pm2 logs?

Comment: Have you canceled nodemon before pm2 start? Also try to run **pm2 start bin/www**. In most of the cases pm2 can't start because port used by node is busy, server reboot should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if your application is listed in PM2, use the command **`pm2 list`**

2) Running apps should  be listed, you can either find an **`online`** or **`errored`** 
status for each app

[image]

3) If your app is **`online`**, try to **`curl localhost:port`** ( if this works, something is wrong with your firewall or nginx / apache configuration)

4) If it is **`errored`**, please check pm2 log   -  ***~/.pm2/pm2.log***'

Answer (score 0):

If pm2.log shows "... had too many unstable restarts ...", try the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651668/3054511